# does u-boot need to be compiled big endian to load zImage in a big endian mode

Tags: u-boot, endianness

I have a `COM-express` module made by `Pactron` and based on `ARMADA XP 78460`. the module support both little and big endian mode.
I was able to compile a big endian version of the kernel (`zImage`), DTS, and root file system (using `Buildroot`) with Marvell `toolchain` for big endian.
Now I am working on compiling a `uboot` (version 2011.12) for big endian but no success so far because I had some issue linking some `ddr3` libraries that are already compiled in little endian and I could't find the correct source files for these libraries.
Now my question, is it necessary to compile u-boot in big endian. I assumed it needs to be compiled in big endian as mentioned in [this HW spec page 95](http://www.marvell.com/embedded-processors/armada-xp/assets/ARMADA-XP-Functional-SpecDatasheet.pdf) that if the image was compiled to Big endian mode, it is the responsability of the image to switch back to big endian mode, but I am not sure.
if it is necessary to compile u-boot in big endian should I contact `pactron` support to send the source files of these libraries. here is the error that I see when I run make

*/home/asoufi/BIGENDIAN/Marvell_toolchain_201301/armebv7-marvell-linux-gnueabi-softfp_i686/bin/../lib/gcc/armeb-marvell-linux-gnueabi/4.6.4/../../../../armeb-marvell-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: ./src_ddr/ddr3_training_axp.lib(ddr3_hw_training.o): compiled for a little endian system and target is big endian*

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you're posting above shows a compile error where yes, you do not have all of your sources being compiled the same way.  Yes, you should start by asking Pactron for support to run your hardware in this manner.

Comment: Thanks Tom, can you please clarify the option of having u-boot compiled in little endian. how would u-boot interact with zImage, DTS, and root file system if u-boot is little endian and all other images (zImage, DTS, and root file system) are in big endian. would this set up be sufficient to claim that my platform is running BIG endian or it is a must to have u-boot executing big endian as well.

Comment: I'm saying that you need (likely) to have the world, including U-Boot, be BE not LE, and thus need to talk with your vendor about whatever apparently binary-only blobs they're giving you (which is a GPL violation).